# How to make a program distinguish between 1-13 INSIDE a raw_input

Tags: python

Hello this is my code:

```
def function():
    n1=1
    n2=2
    n3=3
    n4=4
    n5=5
    n6=6
    n7=7
    n8=8
    n9=9
    n10=10
    n11=11
    n12=12
    n13=13
    n = raw_input("Number (with optional text): ")
    if n1 or n2 or n3 or n4 or n5 or n6 or n7 or n8 or n9 in n:
        print "Not what I want"
    elif n12 or n13 in n:
        print "Dis I want"

function()
```

I'm trying to make that raw_input condition accept that I put a 13 (as it detects that the input has either 1 or 3 in the message) but I just can't (Please, I know I can make a range in a list and then it accepts that I put each number separately, but it's part of a code for another program I'm working on in which the user can put whether words they want, as long as those numbers are input, but then it doesn't distinguish between 1 or 11 for example). Hope you can help :)

Comment: I think there is a logical issue here, from the comments you replied in other answers, clearly you want this "blah blah 9 blah" to check **9** is within 1-13, BUT using `in` will make this "blah blah 999 blah" passes the condition of **9**, **99** and ***999*** within 1-13 as `if "9" in n` has already returned True.

Answer (score 1):

```
if '12' in n or '13' in n:
    print 'OK'
else:
    print 'wrong'
```

if you have more elements in allowed set, it is better to use `any()` with comprehension:

```
if any(str(x) in n for x in range(1, 14)):
    print 'found number from range 1-13 in this string'
```

Comment: +1. But as a quick note: In Python 3.x, `range(1337)` is actually even _better_ than `set(range(1337))`, because it's effectively doing `0 <= x <= 1337` instead of hashing `x` and looking it up. Sadly, in 2.x, `range(1337)` does 1337 comparisons, and so does `xrange(1337)`, so this answer is the best option.

Comment: Actually both set python3 range make little sense here, because OP searches in input, not the other way around. I just realized this :)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 errors, firstly raw_input is returning string, you need to make it to a int. Also as @karthikr pointed out your logic if a bit off.

```
n = raw_input("Number (with optional text): ")
k = int(n)  
if k in [n1, n2, n3]:
    print "Not what I want"
elif k in [n12, n13]:
    print "Dis I want"
```

Comment: The fact is that I need the input to be a string, becouse I want the user to say for example: bla bla 13 bla; detects 13, not 1 nor 3. Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

As OP clearly wants to grab the number from the `raw_input`, I think there is a logical issue if using `in` as conditional check, for example, you want "blah blah 9 blah" to check 9 is within 1-13, BUT using `in` will make this "blah blah 999 blah" passes the condition of **9** within 1-13 as `if "9" in n` has already returned `True`. I don't think that's what OP desired outcome.

So, I am going to suggest using `re` to get the first number out from `raw_input` and do the check. Something like this:

```
import re


def check_number_ok():
    n1, n2, n3, ... = 1, 2, 3, ... # you can assign n1 to n13 like this too
    n = raw_input("Number (with optional text): ")
    check_number = re.compile('\d+')
    check_result = check_number.search(n)
    if check_result is not None:
        first_number = int(check_result.group())
        if first_number == n1:
            # do something here
        elif first_number == n2:
            # do another thing
        # ... check if any others match
        else:
            print "Not what I want"
            return
            # do exit thing here so below code will not run
        # if code runs here which means it passes the check
        print "Dis I want"
    else:
        print "Please at least enter something with a number"
```

Usage:

```
check_number_ok()
Number (with optional text): hello 2 world
Dis I want

check_number_ok()
Number (with optional text): the cat is out 111
Not what I want
```